# Permissions for Creating a Schedule Task

Tags: windows-server-2008

What permissions are needed to create a scheduled task on Windows 2008 with AD:

That error is 0x80070005 in hex. Facility 7 = Windows, error code 5 = Access Denied. The user account used to run this code doesn't have sufficient rights.

Comment: Do you have a user trying to "create" or "run" a scheduled task? Your question is the former, but the error makes it sound like the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the user in the **Backup Operators** or **Server Operators** local group of the server they would schedule the task on. Or you can also do this by modifying the ACL for the tasks folder located in `%SystemRoot%\system32\Tasks\`.

Answer (score 0):

"Act as part of the OS" / "Logon as a service" come to mind for starters if you dont want the user to be a Local Admin on the box.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me at all. "Logon as batch" maybe, but *never never never* as part of the OS. That just gives up the whole boat, huge vulnerability.